# Drupal login form not displaying

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm creating a custom drupal theme and I keep getting locked out of my site because I can't log back in.

I have the default login block in the content region, but when I log out it doesn't show up when I go to localhost:8888/nations_dp/?q=user

I'll post a screenshot of my blocks once I get logged back in by changing the theme and stuff.

Comment: is it possible that you are already logged in. so you dont see it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the visibility settings for the block, and checked it is displaying for anonymous users?